# Error: "JsonWebTokenError: jwt must be provided"

Tags: node.js, reactjs, cookies, routes, jwt

I am using jsonwebtoken in my  middleware function for verification. But in my middleware function I am not getting any token but in my database token is generated . I am not understanding what is the problem.
I tried to console log authmiddleware but it was showing that No token is provided.

[image: Screenshot of the error]

useModel.js:

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const validator = require("validator");
const bcrypt = require("bcryptjs");
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");

const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  fname: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    trim: true,
  },
  email: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    unique: true,
    validate(value) {
      if (!validator.isEmail(value)) {
        throw new Error("Not valid email address");
      }
    },
  },
  mobile: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    unique: true,
  },
  password: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    minlength: 6,
  },
  cpassword: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    minlength: 6,
  },
  tokens: [
    {
      token: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
      },
    },
  ],
  carts: Array,
});


// password hasing
userSchema.pre("save", async function (next) {
  if (this.isModified("password")) {
    this.password = await bcrypt.hash(this.password, 12);
    this.cpassword = await bcrypt.hash(this.cpassword, 12);
  }
  next();
});

// password hashing
userSchema.pre("save", async function (next) {
  if (this.isModified("password")) {
    const saltRounds = 12;
    this.password = await bcrypt.hash(this.password, saltRounds);
    this.cpassword = await bcrypt.hash(this.cpassword, saltRounds);
  }
  next();
});

// generating token
userSchema.methods.generateAuthToken = async function () {
  try {
    const token = jwt.sign({ _id: this._id }, process.env.JWT_SECRET, {
      expiresIn: "1d",
    });

    this.tokens = this.tokens.concat({ token });
    await this.save();

    return token;
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
};

// add to cart data
userSchema.methods.addToCart = async function (cart) {
  try {
    this.carts.push(cart);
    await this.save();
    return this.carts;
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("Error occurred while adding to cart: ", error);
  }
};
const User = new mongoose.model("USER", userSchema);

module.exports = User;
```

Authmiddleware.js:

```
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");
const User = require("../models/userSchema");

const authmiddleware = async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    const token = req.cookies.Amazon_website;

    

    const verifyToken = jwt.verify(token, process.env.JWT_SECRET);

    const rootUser = await User.findOne({
      _id: verifyToken._id,
      "tokens.token": token,
    });

    if (!rootUser) {
      throw new Error("User Not Found");
    }

    req.token = token;
    req.rootUser = rootUser;
    req.userID = rootUser._id;

    next();
  } catch (error) {
    if (error.name === "TokenExpiredError") {
      res.status(401).send("Unauthorized: Token has expired");
    } else {
      res.status(401).send("Unauthorized: No token provided");
    }
    console.log(error);
  }
};

module.exports = authmiddleware;
```

Controller.js:

```
const Products = require("../models/productSchema");
const User = require("../models/userSchema");
const bcrypt = require("bcryptjs");
//Login Controller
const loginController = async (req, res) => {
  const { email, password } = req.body;
  if (!email || !password) {
    res.status(400).json({
      error: "Fill the data",
    });
    // console.log("No data available");
  }

  try {
    const userlogin = await User.findOne({ email: email });
    // console.log(userlogin);
    if (userlogin) {
      const isMatch = await bcrypt.compare(password, userlogin.password);
      console.log(isMatch);

      if (!isMatch) {
        res.status(400).json({ error: "Invalid crediential pass" });
      } else {
        const token = await userlogin.generateAuthToken();
        console.log(token);

        res.cookie("Amazon_website", token, {
          expires: new Date(Date.now() + 1800000),
          httpOnly: true,
        });
        res.status(201).json(userlogin);
      }
    } else {
      res.status(400).json({ error: "User doesn't exist" });
    }
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(400).json({
      error: "Invalid Details",
    });
  }
};

//logout controller
const logoutController = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    req.rootUser.tokens = req.rootUser.tokens.filter((currentelement) => {
      return currentelement.token !== req.token;
    });

    res.clearCookie("Amazon_website", { path: "/" });
    req.rootUser.save();
    res.status(201).json(req.rootUser.tokens);
    console.log("user logout");
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
};
//Add cart item
const addtocartController = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const { id } = req.params;
    const cart = await Products.findOne({ id: id });
    console.log(cart + "Data of cart");

    const userContact = await User.findOne({ _id: req.userID });
    console.log(userContact + " Get User");

    if (userContact) {
      const cartData = await userContact.addTOCartData(cart);
      await userContact.save();
      console.log(cartData);
      res.status(201).json(userContact);
    } else {
      res.status(401).json({
        error: "Invalid User",
      });
    }
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(400).json({
      error: "Invalid User",
    });
  }
};
module.exports = {
  loginController,
  logoutController,
  addtocartController 
};
```

userRoutes.js:

```
const express = require("express");
const {
 
  loginController,
  logoutController
  
} = require("../controller/Controller");

const authmiddleware = require("../middleware/Authmiddleware");

//router abject
const router = new express.Router();

//POST  || login
router.post("/login", loginController);

//GET || logout
router.get("/logout", authmiddleware, logoutController);


module.exports = router;
```

cartRoutes.js:

```
const express = require("express");
const {
  addtocartController,
  cartDetailsController,
  deletecartItemController,
} = require("../controller/Controller");

const authmiddleware = require("../middleware/Authmiddleware");

//router abject
const router = new express.Router();

//POST  || add data into cart
router.post("/addtocart/:id", authmiddleware, addtocartController);

//GET || Get cart items
router.get("/cartdetails", authmiddleware, cartDetailsController);

//DELETE || remove item from cart
router.delete("/remove/:id", authmiddleware, deletecartItemController);

module.exports = router;
```

server.js:

```
const express = require("express");
const colors = require("colors");
const morgan = require("morgan");
const dotenv = require("dotenv");
const cors = require("cors"); // Import the cors package
const connectDB = require("./config/db");
const Products = require("./models/productSchema");
const DefaultData = require("./defaultdata.");
const cookieParser = require("cookie-parser");
dotenv.config();

connectDB();

const app = express();

app.use(express.json());
app.use(cors({ origin: "http://localhost:3000", credentials: true }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(morgan("dev"));

app.use("/api/v1/user", require("./routes/userRoutes"));
app.use("/api/v1/product", require("./routes/productRoutes"));
app.use("/api/v1/cart", require("./routes/cartRoutes"));

const port = process.env.PORT || 8080;

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(
    `Server is running in ${process.env.NODE_MODE} Mode on port ${process.env.PORT}`
      .bgCyan.white
  );
});

DefaultData();
```

Wherever I am using authmiddleware function in that file I am getting this jsonwebtoken error. I am not understanding what is the issue. It was work fine. But after I upload the backend into a site and try to run the app then the error occurred . After that I again tried to run from the localhost:8080 but now it is not working anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Please print the token before **const verifyToken = jwt.verify(token, process.env.JWT_SECRET);**

Check this question.

[Having trouble with JsonWebToken; JsonWebToken Error: JWT must be provided](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48476625/having-trouble-with-jsonwebtoken-jsonwebtoken-error-jwt-must-be-provided)

Comment: It shows: 
Token: undefined

Comment: I update the code with my userModel.js . Where the token was generating